# How do I use the return value from a function in a Vim command?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do something which sound super easy, but for some reason it's not working. The command:

```
:m 10
```

moves the current line to right below line 10, and

```
:echo line(".") - 2
```

prints out the line number of the line two lines up from the cursor. After reading the documentation, I wrote this command:

```
:m line(".") - 2
```

It resulted in this error:

> M14: Invalid address

So I figured that functions aren't evaluated unless I use the `=` symbol, so I tried:

```
:m =line(".") - 2
```

Which gave me the same error. Just to be sure the spaces wasn't the cause, I tried:

```
:m =line(".")
```

Which still gives me the same error! **What am I doing wrong here?**

---

I have made sure that `:m` accepts integers and that `line()` returns integers.

```
:echo type(5)
0
:echo type(line("."))
0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to evaluate an expression and pass it to a ex-mode command, you need to use the `execute` command. In your case, this works:

```
:execute "m" line(".") - 2
```

You can think of `execute` as a function taking a single variable `"m" line(".") - 2`. This variable is evaluated and then executed as a string in ex-mode.

For more help, see `:help execute`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use a relative address like so:

```
:m-2
```

For more help see:

```
:h range
```

Comment: +1 A much better solution to my problem, thanks! The other answer answered the question though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your original answer was almost right:

```
:m <C-R>=line(".") - 2
```

Would have worked. The other solutions are also correct, but you should take a look at the vim documentation about the expression register (`:h quote_=`) and I'm sure you'll find something interesting!

Comment: +1 I'm amazed at how awesome all the answers to this questions are :P

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm asking this question is to make a key mapping that moves the current line up or down. Can this method be mapped to a key? When I try I just get the same error as the one I quote in the question.

Comment: You may want to check out unimpaired.vim by Tim Pope. Provides the mappings `[e` and `]e` to exchange lines. https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired